# SUM(LAST()) on GROUP BY

Tags: influxdb

I have a series, `disk,` that contains a `path` (`/mnt/disk1`, `/mnt/disk2`, etc) and `total` space of a disk. It also includes `free` and `used` values. These values are updated at a specified interval. What I would like to do, is query to get the sum of the `total` of the `last()` of each path. I would also like to do the same for `free` and for `used`, to get a aggregate of the total size, free space, and used space of all of my disks on my server.

I have a query here that will get me the `last(total)` of all the disks, grouped by its path (for distinction):

`select last(total) as total from disk where path =~ /(mnt\/disk).*/ group by path`

Currently, this returns 5 series, each containing 1 row (the latest) and the value of its `total`. I then want to take the sum of those series, but I cannot just wrap the `last(total)` into a `sum()` function call. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Over here, they talk about nested functions which aren't yet generally supported in InfluxDB. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6823 . The workaround suggested is to build a CQ for one value (e.g. total) and query the CQ using the other function (e.g. last() ).

Answer (score 2):

Carrying on from my comment above about nested functions.

Building a toy example:

```
CREATE DATABASE FOO
USE FOO
```

Assuming your data is updated at intervals *greater than*[1] every minute:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY disk_sum_total ON FOO 
BEGIN
  SELECT sum("total") AS "total_1m" INTO disk_1m_total FROM "disk" 
  GROUP BY time(1m)
END
```

Then push some values in:

```
INSERT disk,path="/mnt/disk1" total=30
INSERT disk,path="/mnt/disk2" total=32
INSERT disk,path="/mnt/disk3" total=33
```

And wait more than a minute. Then:

```
INSERT disk,path="/mnt/disk1" total=41
INSERT disk,path="/mnt/disk2" total=42
INSERT disk,path="/mnt/disk3" total=43
```

And wait a minute+ again. Then:

```
SELECT * FROM disk_1m_total

name: disk_1m_total
-------------------
time                    total_1m
1476015300000000000     95
1476015420000000000     126
```

The two values are `30+32+33=95` and `41+42+43=126`.

From there, it's trivial to query:

```
SELECT last(total_1m) FROM disk_1m_total

name: disk_1m_total
-------------------
time                    last
1476015420000000000     126
```

Hope that helps.

[1] Picking intervals smaller than the update frequency prevents minor timing jitters from making all the data being accidentally summed twice for a given group. There might be some "zero update" intervals, but no "double counting" intervals. I typically run the query twice as fast as the updates. If the CQ sees no data for a window, there will be no CQ performed for that window, so `last()` will still give the correct answer. For example, I left the CQ running overnight and pushed no new data in: `last(total_1m)` gives the same answer, not zero for "no new data".